# Headers in Microsoft Word

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2013

I'm using Microsoft Word 2013, and I set the footer with a page number on the left for even pages and on the right for odd pages.

Now I want to set the header in the way to write the chapter name on the left for even pages and on the right for odd pages. The problem is that when i write the chapter name in a header all the odd/even pages take that value. How can i set the headers of a single chapter?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want different headers/footers on different pages you need to work with [section breaks](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/word-help/insert-a-section-break-HA010031073.aspx).

[Here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/word-help/headers-and-footers-from-basic-to-elaborate-RZ001021662.aspx?section=21) is an article from Microsoft explaining. It is also explained [here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/word-help/insert-the-chapter-number-and-title-in-a-header-or-footer-HP005189361.aspx).

> The section break allows completely different headers and footers.

And [here](http://www.howtogeek.com/103481/how-to-use-multiple-headers-and-footers-in-a-single-document/) is an article from HowToGeek explaining "How To Use Multiple Headers and Footers in a Single Document".

BTW. If you are typing the chapter title manually in the header/footer you might want to consider using "dynamic text fields". This is explained [here](http://www.bloggpro.com/dynamic-text-fields-in-word-header/). That way when you change your chapter-name it's automatically changed in the header/footer.

[image: HowToGeek]

Answer (score 0):

If your Chapter titles appear in the body of the text, e.g. if each is in a Heading 1 style paragraph, then you may be able to get away with nothing more than a { STYLEREF } field in the header, e.g. like this:

```
{ STYLEREF 1 }
```

(You can insert these things from Insert->Quick parts->Field